# How can I use ParseIntPipe and Dto together?

Tags: nestjs, dto

From query I get limit param.
How to transform into number and check by Dto ?

```
  @Get('currency/:type')
  getCurrency(
    @Param() params: CurrencyTypeDto,
    @Query('limit', ParseIntPipe) limit: number,
    @Query() query: PaginationLimitDto
  ) {
```

PaginationLimitDto

```
export class PaginationLimitDto {
    @IsOptional()
    @IsInt()
    limit: number;
}
```

Comment: By "check by Dto", do you mean use Nest's `ValdiationPipe`?

Comment: transform to int from string and check by dto

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Query and URL parameters always come in as an object of strings, just howthe underlying engines handle them. What you can do, with your DTO, is add the `@Transform()` decorator and do something like

```js
export class PaginationLimitDto {
  @IsOptional()
  @IsInt()
  // pre 0.3.2 syntax
  @Transform(val => Number.parseInt(val))
  // after 0.3.2 syntax*
  @Transform({ value } => Number.parseInt(value))
  limit: number;
}
```

Then you only need `@Query() query: PaginationLimitDto` in your method handler. Nest's `ValidationPipe` will take care of calling `class-transformer` and `class-validator` for you.

*See [changelog on Github](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md#032-breaking-change---2021-01-14)

Answer (score 5):

The updated syntax for `@Transorm` decorator.

```
import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';

export class Photo {
  id: number;

  @Transform(({ value }) => parseInt(value))
  index: number;
}
```

Comment: This is the current correct answer as of 9/25/22. Ignore the accepted answer since it has been updated.